# How can I disable *Web Beautify Errors* from the Emacs web-beautify package?

Tags: emacs, error-messaging, js-beautify

I use the `web-beautify` package. And, while I'm tangling my `org-mode` files to html, css and js files, every time I tangle these, error pop-up messages come in a new buffer. That annoys me a great deal. How do I disable those?

(Note: the message come in a `*Web Beautify Errors*` buffer.)

Comment: Is `web-beautify` (in your question text) different to `js-beautify` (in your tags) ?

Comment: Yes. web-beatify uses js-beatify under the hood

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think that all you can sensibly do is suppress this buffer when Emacs tries to display it, because displaying it is hard-coded in `web-beautify-format-region` which sets the `DISPLAY-ERROR-BUFFER` argument when it calls `shell-command-on-region`.

I think this will do the trick:

```el
;; Avoid displaying the *Web Beautify Errors* buffer.
(add-to-list 'display-buffer-alist
             (cons "\\*Web Beautify Errors\\*"
                   (cons 'display-buffer-no-window
                         '((allow-no-window . t)))))
```

Comment: That works! Thank you. And sorry for taking a month to give feedback if it worked